# Сохранить соотношение сторон картинки в ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

Вопрос простой: как сохранить соотношение сторон картинки? Я попробовал несколькими широко известными способами. Устанавливал `android:adjustViewBounds`,но он работает только при

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит установить конкретную высоту, как соотношение нарушается:

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу ниже используемый код (удалил сторонние элементы)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="65dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_lesson" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Собственно, что я упускаю? Или ConstraintLayout накладывает свои особенности? Подскажите, пожалуйста оптимальное решение.

Comment: Попробовал у себя эту разметку - все отлично. Возможно вырезали что-то важное) или покажите каким образом сетаете картинки

Comment: Убрал пару лишних лейблов, они точно никак не связаны) А устанавливаю вот так: image.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, R.drawable.no_lessons_1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используя `image.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, R.drawable.no_lessons_1)` вы меняете фон виджета. Оно и логично что будет растягивать.

Используйте `image.setImageDrawable()`

Comment: отлично, на будущие постараюсь не путать))) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поменять в `ImageView` `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` на  `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: проверил, поведение точно такое же